# I can be pure and good - what am I?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

I can be pure and good but I'll make fools look thick,

I can be bird and fish, but I'll swim like a brick,

I can be heart and star but I'd rather be bar,

I can be plastic and leaf but I can come from a jar.

What am I?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are:

> Gold

I can be pure and good but I'll make fools look thick,

> Good as gold, fool's gold

I can be bird and fish, but I'll swim like a brick,

> Goldfinch, goldfish, gold brick (or just referring to the fact that gold will sink)

I can be heart and star but I'd rather be bar,

> Heart of gold, gold star, gold bars

I can be plastic and leaf but I can come from a jar.

> <s>Had to Google - apparently "[gold plastic syndrome](http://tfwiki.net/wiki/Gold_Plastic_Syndrome)" is a thing</s> OP was referring to gold (credit) cards. Gold leaf, gold is often sold in tiny jars as souvenirs

What am I?

> Gold!

Comment: Dammit, typing it up as you posted! The plastic thing was also the best I could find for that clue

Comment: Well done!  +1 :)